# How to make Microsoft apps use Edge although my default browser is Firefox?

Tags: file-association, default-settings

I use Firefox as my default browser on Windows11 but I'd like Edge to be used when I click a link inside Microsoft apps like Teams/Office/OneNote etc. Based on my research, I don't think this is possible via System Settings. Is there some other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make any app use a second Default Browser.

There is only one Default Browser (not two or multiple).

So if Firefox has been set as your default Browser, then anything you wish to open with Edge must be done manually.

That will be the easiest way overall.

I set Chromium Edge to be my Default and then open other things with other Browsers manually. That is (for me) the line of least resistance.

You can do the following:

In an Administrative Command Prompt, you can start Edge as follows:

start msedge wwww.google.com or any website.

That may help you but as I noted it seems easiest to do this manually from Edge itself.